# how to exectute python script in a running docker container?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, anaconda, conda

I am trying to execute a python script inside a docker container with

```
docker exec -it container bash -c "cd /test;python3 test.py /home/test/data/"
```

I get error

```
ImportError: No module named 'flask_user'
```

When I try

```
docker exec -it container bash
```

and then type

```
cd /test
python3 test.py /home/test/data/
```

everything works fine. Why?

I am using anaconda.

I tried:

```
docker exec -it lost bash -c "conda"
```

then I get bash: conda: command not found

Comment: Can you provide a Dockerfile describing your image's content, and the corresponding `docker run` command?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution:

```
docker exec -it container bash -c "source /opt/conda/bin/activate ENVIRONMENT;cd /test;python3 test.py /home/test/data/"
```